# xpath search on subtree

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I need to restrict the xpath node search to a subtree. I'm currently using the method below but it searches on a whole document regardlest whether I give it the document or the node I want to search from.

```
private NodeList findNodes(Object obj,String xPathString) throws ... {
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    XPathExpression expression = xPath.compile(xPathString);
    return (NodeList) expression.evaluate(obj, XPathConstants.NODESET);
}
```

Solution I'm using now is that I create new document, append the node and search on the new document, then merge. I want to improve this. Can it be done?

The XPath I'm using is `//nodeName`.

Comment: show us the xpath you're using

Comment: I believe the restriction would have to be made in the XPath expression.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're looking on the `//` axis which means 'any descendant node of the document root',

Change it to `.//` axis (descendands of the context node) and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 12):

**You need to distinguish between an** *absolute* and *relative* **XPath expression**.

Good question +1.

In XPath, any expression that starts with `/` is *absolute XPath expression*. An absolute XPath expression is evaluated on the complete *current document*.

By contrast, a *relative* XPath expression is evaluated off the current  (context) node.

**This explains the reported problem**: `//nodeName` is an absolute XPath expression.

**What you want is a relative XPath expression**, such as:

```
.//nodeName
```

Answer (score 3):

`.//nodeName` will search for a `nodeName` element anywhere within the given context node.